# find next lowest and next highest value in group from table y given a value in table x

Tags: r, tidyverse

Table X contains a list of groups and measured coordinates, e.g:

X:
(group, measured coordinate)
A 10
A 20
B 10

Table Y contains a list of interesting coordinates, e.g.

Y:
(group, interesting coordinate)
A 3
A 5
A 25
B 15

I want to find the distance between the closest interesting coordinate in Y given my coordinates in X, so the output would be

Z
(group, measured coordinate, distance to nearest lower coordinate, distance to nearest higher coordinate)
A 10 7 15
A 20 13 5
B 25 10 NA

Any idea how this could be done in tidyverse/R?

Comment: How is the data and distances from `X: B 10` to `Y: B 15` become `Z: B 25, 10, NA`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way. The code creates a flag to see if it's the first or last row in each group of `group` and `coordinate`. Then computes the distances and reshapes to wide format. There are probably simpler ways but it does what the question asks for.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

left_join(X, Y, by = "group", suffix = c("", ".y")) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(flag = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(coordinate) == 0L))) %>%
  group_by(group, coordinate) %>%
  mutate(flag = flag == first(flag) | flag == last(flag)) %>%
  filter(flag) %>%
  select(-flag) %>%
  mutate(distance = abs(coordinate - coordinate.y),
         which_dist = ifelse(row_number() == 1L, "first", "last")) %>%
  select(-coordinate.y) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = -distance,
    names_from = which_dist,
    values_from = distance
  )
## A tibble: 3 x 4
## Groups:   group, coordinate [3]
#  group coordinate first  last
#  <chr>      <int> <int> <int>
#1 A             10     7    15
#2 A             20    17     5
#3 B             10     5    NA
```